# When System.Data.DataTable is derived how does DataTable.Clone return the derived class?

Tags: .net

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx "If these classes have been derived, the clone will also be of the same derived classes".

In the example code below how does the clone method on the base class "know" to create the derived class?

```
public class MyDataTable : System.Data.DataTable
        {
            public override System.Data.DataTable Clone()
            {
                //How is this a MyDataTable not a "DataTable" ?
                return base.Clone();
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyDataTable dt = new MyDataTable();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(dt.Clone() is MyDataTable);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dig through the code for DataTable with Reflector, you'll encounter this method, called by the private Clone(DataSet) method:

```
protected virtual DataTable CreateInstance()
{
    return (DataTable) Activator.CreateInstance(base.GetType(), true);
}
```

In other words, it creates a new instance of your class, not DataTable.  Be careful, this clone will have a deep copy of the typical DataTable properties but any fields you might have added but do not assign in your constructor will have their default values.

Answer (score 1):

When a System.Data.DataTable is cloned, it calls the protected DataTable member CreateInstance that ultimately uses the Activator class to construct the underlying DataTable type.

```
protected virtual DataTable CreateInstance()
{
    return (DataTable) Activator.CreateInstance(base.GetType(), true);
}
```

Where GetType will return the actual Type reference to MyDataTable. Remember that even through you are calling GetType in the base class, it will return the actual instance type of MyDataTable. Also as a note, the Activator class is a simplfied way of constructing new objects based on type data without having to manually use reflection to lookup the ConstructorInfo to create a new instance of an object.

You can find more information on the Activator class on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx)

A fantastic program for looking in to these type of questions is [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) (it's free!). Reflector allows you to look at the internals of any assembly to see what is actually happening.